# Extend LVM on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, ext4

how can I add the rest of the 19.5GB from `sda2` to `vg00-lv01`? I tried `lvextend` but this tells me `Insufficient free space: 512 extents needed, but only 0 available`.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.4.

```
NAME          FSTYPE       SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
    sda                         20G            
    ├─sda1        ext4         487M /boot      
    └─sda2        LVM2_member 19.5G            
      ├─vg00-lv00 swap         1.9G [SWAP]     
      └─vg00-lv01 ext4         7.6G /          
    sr0                       1024M
```

Output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x520f1760

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048   999423   997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       999424 41943039 40943616 19.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

Output of `pvs -a`

```
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda1            ---      0     0 
  /dev/sda2  vg00 lvm2 a--  <9.52g    0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resize both the physical volume and the logical volume within.

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
lvextend /dev/vg00-lvol1 /dev/sda2 # grow the LV by the amount of free PV
fsadm resize /dev/vg00/lvol1       # grow the FS within the LV
```